# Accessing the data inside a array of json object to auto select a value in the dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs, json

How can i auto select the value from a dropdown by comparing with the data from my angular model.

json :

```
 {"EmployeeI9Docs":[
{"List":"","DocumentTypeId":7,"DocumentTitle":"Driver's license or ID card","DocumentIssuer":"DMV","DocumentNumber":"D998799","ExpirationDate":"2019-11-21T00:00:00"}
]
}
```

js file  :

```
 EVerifyModule.controller('EVerifyI9Controller', ['$scope', '$http', 'EVerifyModuleI9Service',  function ($scope, $http, EVerifyModuleI9Service) {
    $scope.i9doctypes = [];

    //Get the employee Info
   EVerifyModuleI9Service.getEmployeeInformation(sessionStorage.ceId).then(function (response) {
        if (response != null) {
            alert(response.data.EmployeeInfo.DocumentTitle);
            $scope.employeeInfo = response.data.EmployeeInfo;   
        }
   });
    // Get the doc types (Lookup) for Dropdowns ListA, ListB, ListC.
   EVerifyModuleI9Service.GetI9DocTypes().then(function (response) {
       $scope.i9doctypes = response.data;
   });

}]);
```

HTML :

```
<div>
    <select name="ListA" class="form-control input-md"
            ng-disabled="selectedOptionB || selectedOptionC"
            ng-model="employeeInfo.EmployeeI9Docs[0].DocumentTitle"
            data-toggle="tooltip"
            data-original-title="{{selectedOptionA.description}}"
            ng-options="doc.brief for doc in i9doctypes | filter:{list:'A'} | orderBy:'index' track by doc.id">
     <option value=""> </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to change.
1.  ng-model should be something like

`$scope.selectedEmployeeId;`

2. Change ng-options to:

`ng-options="doc.DocumentNumber as doc.DocumentNumber for doc in i9doctypes"`